# Unable to use gmsh from Visual Studio C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, gmsh

1. I downloaded the sdk and ran the Windows related commands described [here](https://gitlab.onelab.info/gmsh/gmsh/tree/master/tutorial/c++).
2. Then I created a new VC++ project and copied the contents of a tutorial file included with that sdk (t1.cpp).
3. There were compile time errors, which I fixed by including the path to gmsh.h in the include settings found in projcet->Properties->Configuration Properties->C/C++->General->Additional Include Directories.
4. I also included path to the gmsh.lib file at projcet->Properties->Configuration Properties->Linker->General->Additional Libraries Directories.

Still I am getting the below error while trying to build the project:

```
LNK2019:    unresolved external symbol gmshFree referenced in function "int __cdecl gmsh::model::geo::addCurveLoop(class std::vector<int,class std::allocator<int> > const &,int,bool)" (?addCurveLoop@geo@model@gmsh@@YAHAEBV?$vector@HV?$allocator@H@std@@@std@@H_N@Z)
```

Please say what I am missing here. I am running Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 (Version 16.10.4) on Windows 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you add #include "gmsh.h " and add gmsh.lib in Configuration Properties > Linker > Input? For more information, you could refer to the document: [Create a client app that uses the DLL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-dynamic-link-library-cpp?view=msvc-160#create-the-dll-project).

Comment: I hadn't included the lib by name just added its path to Additional Library Directories. Is there a way to avoid doing this every time?

Comment: You can try another way to use DLL: #pragma comment(lib,"the lib path/gmsh.lib").